# How to persist/cache data in cross platform Mono App (eg. Xamarin Framework)?

Tags: caching, xamarin.ios, persistence, xamarin.android, key-value-store

I'm looking for a good solution to store and/or cache data in a cross platform App developed in C# (Xamarin's MonoTouch & MonoDroid + WindowsPhone). Simple Key/Value Pairs would be sufficient. The stored data will to be used as general caching and as persistence to show something on App startup while new data is fetched from the server.

[Akavache](https://github.com/github/Akavache) looks very much like what I want but how to integrate it in my projects? Will it choose the right path's for storing? Are there similar libraries around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried Akavache jet but rather implemented a [cross-plattform wrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleStorage/) around the preference APIs on Android and iOS:

```
var storage = SimpleStorage.EditGroup("group name of key/value store");
storage.Put("myKey", "some value");
var value = storage.Get("myKey");
```

The project is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/SimpleStorage) and distributed as a free [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleStorage/). Along string storing it also provides async/await methods and serializing/deserializing of complex objects.

Comment: You didn't mention that SimpleStorage doesn't support expiring objects, which is THE most important aspect of any Caching solution.

Comment: SimpleStorage is only meant to help you with persistence of settings and flags. You could build a caching system on top of it but the intention of this lib is to provide simple access to the platforms own preferences APIs.

Comment: please edit your reply mentioning that it lacks Caching to avoid wasting other people's time thinking it supports Caching while it doesn't

Comment: @Korayem the storage mechanism it uses is not for caching anyway. It uses user preference storage it is exactly for simple key value storage.

Comment: @rodja @andrey the question is asking about both `persist` and `cache`. The suggested solution `SimpleStorage` doesn't support `Cache` hence the answer need to explicitly state that to avoid wasting other people's time.

Comment: @Korayem answer is good enough. Author is not required to present full detalization, links are provided for interested.

Comment: Is there any way to set a memory limit of in-memory-cache?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just use `XmlSerializer` or something you are used to using in .Net.  You can just change the path the file is stored to depending on the platform.

Akavache looks promising, but it looks a little overkill if you only need a couple key-value pairs.

Comment: Caching is all about expiring the data after a period of time. Without that, it's just data persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Akavache will automatically set the correct paths on both iOS and Android, it will use information from your app (from AndroidManifest.xml on Android and your info.plist on iOS).

Comment: Can I use Akavache without RxUI? Or are there any samples or documentation about Akavache? Just a simple REST call and cache the result sample?

Comment: Akavache has a dependency on ReactiveUI's Core DLL. You don't have to actually use ReactiveUI though.